# PayPal recurring payments using express checkout order summary

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am trying to setup PayPal recurring payments using express checkout. I follow instructions [here](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/recurring_payment_ec/dotnet?interactive=ON&env=sandbox).
Although that code has bugs on its own, I got it to work. Now I want to customize order summary on PayPal side, but I cannot get it to work.. Basicly, now, when user is redirected to PayPal, user in order summary can only see "recurringbilling" like in picture below: [image]

"Recurring billing details here" is value for `baType.BillingAgreementDescription` PayPal's example.

I would like to show information in that place about order, he is purchasing, something like in pic below: [image]

I tried to add info to `paymentDetail.PaymentDetailsItem` (`List<PaymentDetailsItemType>`), but all it shows is that description anyway. Maybe I am missing something, but can anyone help about this? Also, where can I include something like my receipt number to link this to my database?